# IFrame issue with Response.Redirect()

Tags: asp.net, iframe

I have a master page with a menu and an Iframe.  When I click on the menu items pages are loaded inside the iframe.  On each page I'm checking for the logged in user sessions and if they are null I'm redirecting the user to the Login.aspx page.

My issue is when the sessions are null page is redirected to the Login.aspx but it's loading inside the
iframe. If the sessions are null I need the user to be redirected to the Login page with out loading inside the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behaviour of an iframe. The 'target' property of a link can be used to escape this, like

```
<a href="..." target="_top">Escape!</a>
```

If you want to do it in a redirect, try this link:
http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/forms/how-do-i-change-the-target-frame-or-window-of-a-response-redirect.html

If you *always* want a form to redirect out of the iframe, you can set the target property of the form you're posting back from.